# Change <audio> tag src by function

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm making an audio player script that changes the `src=""` of the `<audio>` tag, I don't like doing  because I'm not doing tracks.

The user clicks on this link:

```
<a href="#play" onclick="playAudio('song.mp3');">Play</a>
```

Then this receives the function:

```
   function playAudio(file)
    {
    var audio = file;
    }
    if(audio !== '') {
    document.getElementById('player').src = 'music/'+audio;
    }
    else {

    }
```

For this player:

```
<audio id="player" src="" controls></audio>
```

I've tried changing different things about the script but it's no good.

*Why won't it change the audio?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function ends at the start, because you have the closing brace `}` in the wrong place:

```
function playAudio(file)
    {
    var audio = file;
    }
```

This should be written as:

```
 function playAudio(file)
    {
    var audio = file;
    if(audio !== '') {
    document.getElementById('player').src = 'music/'+audio;
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Also, `id` isnt a `href`, this should be:

```
<a href="#play" id="play" onclick="playAudio('song.mp3');">Play</a>
```